# Where is .pk8 file in Android

Tags: android, security, code-signing, pem

I need to sign my app using the **.pem** and **.pk8** file, I managed to get the .pem file but can't seem to find the location for .pk8 file inside the device.

Anyone, Any ideas? 
Do u need a rooted device to get that file?

Comment: It is unclear what you are talking about. For signing an APK file you don't need to do any modifications on the device.

Comment: I need to sign the app with system certificates, instead of my own. These certificates directly belong to the ROM of the device and I need them for special purposes.

Comment: I still don't see the problem just use [apksigner](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner) from Android SDK and sign the app using the keys you have.

Comment: My problem is not that simple. Look, I’m developing application for VR headsets and there’s no way the user can click on the accept button of permission dialogs. I want my application to automatically assign all the permissions at the time of installation so there’s no pop ups asking for permissions. The devices are in house devices and won’t be uploaded to play store, all these devices are ‘Managed Devices’. I hope this clears the problem

Comment: And therefore you want to sign the app using the system signature. Are you aware that only the ROM creator has the signature key. Therefore if you want to create a system signature you also need to use your own custom ROM. The private key you need for signing can usually not be found on the device itself.